# Python web layout library like Golden Layout

Tags: python, flask, layout, golden-layout

Golden Layout seems to be a really interesting JS layout library. For an app currently developed in Flask, is there anything similar in Python that would integrate well with Flask?

Answer (score 0):

With jinja2, You can use panel from holoviz.

Look this example

https://panel.holoviz.org/gallery/demos/VTKSlicer.html#demos-gallery-vtkslicer